# Add projection to morphia query

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

When doing queries with Morphia is it possible to limit the returned fields (specify a projection)?

Like this on the command line:
db.Institution.find({name: /^Berlin/}, {slug:1})

Or this with the Java driver:
BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject("slug", 1);
collection.find(new BasicDBObject(),projection);

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this https://morphia.dev/1.5/guides/querying/#projections ?
[I Know it's late but worth for new visitors]

Answer (score 1):

You do, see https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Query#Ignoring_Fields

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^Berlin");
Query<InsitutionEntity> query = mongoDataStore.find(InsitutionEntity.class)
    .field("name").equal(regex)
    .retrievedFields(true, "slug").asList();
```

(Didn't test it, but it should work like this)

Comment: Doesnt work for me using Morphia 1.1.0.

`List<User> list = ds.find(User.class).retrievedFields(false, "password").asList();`

This still returns all the `User` documents with the `password` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject();
filter.append("name", "whoever");

BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject();
projection.append("fieldOne", 1); // 1 == True, it shows the Field.
projection.append("fieldTwo", 1);
projection.append("_id", 0) // 0 == False, it does not show the "_id"

List list = MorphiaObject.datastore.getCollection(MyClass.class).find(filter, projection).toArray();
for (Object each : list) {
    System.out.println("Each: " + each.toString());
}
```